# Is it with spaces or without spaces when sending card number to Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-8

I am new to `Stripe` so I want to know if there is a `card number`, say 4242 4242 4242 4242, should I remove the spaces in the card number or not when calling Stripe API ?

Answer (score 2):

Passing card details directly to the API is not recommended and carries PCI compliance consequences. Instead, you should be collecting card and other payment details using Elements.
https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element

That said, if you do need to pass card numbers, you can see an example in the token create request snippet here, without spaces in the card number:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card